# timeout parameter in runTransaction does not work

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my transaction timeouts. The timeout always takes around 9 seconds independent of how I set the timeout parameter.

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final docref = db.collection('appdata').doc(docID);
    final data = {'rueckruf': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()};
    
    db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      transaction.update(docref, data);
    }, timeout: Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      //transaction did work do sth.                         
    }, onError: (e) {
      //transaction did not work do sth.
    });
```

Comment: I posted an issue in the respective GitHub Project: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9118